# PHP search returns correct results but with bind_param error

Tags: php, mysqli

In PHP I have a function to return results for a search form with 2 fields. Here's how I create the SQL query:

```
$query = "SELECT itemnumber, manufacturer, name, price
    FROM books WHERE $searchtype LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchterm);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($itemnumber, $manufacturer, $name, $price);
```

Testing this, I searched for:

- Search type: manufacturer
- Search term: tree

The results page displayed the result correct but with the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in...
```

Any advice on why that error displays?

Initially, I had it like so:

```
$query = "SELECT itemnumber, manufacturer, name, price
    FROM books WHERE $searchtype = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $searchterm);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($itemnumber, $manufacturer, $name, $price);
```

The problem is that it required an exact match. For example, if I searched for "Tree" I wouldn't get any results. But if I searched for "Tree Company" which is the value in the database, I would get a result. This worked without errors.

Comment: You bind a param which is never used in query.

Comment: $searchtype is also prone to sql injection

Comment: Your initial query was closer, but you need to add the `%` symbols either end of the string before you pass it in. Something like `$stmt->bind_param("s", "%". $searchterm . "%");` Your new code doesn't have any parameters in the query, hence you can't bind values.

Comment: @droopsnoot ony it has to be `...["%". $searchterm . "%"]`